# Firebase -Auth.auth().currentUser?.phoneNumber returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I verify and link the user's phone number using the following:

```
let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationId, verificationCode: verificationCode)

Auth.auth().currentUser?.link(with: credential, completion: { [weak self](authDataResult, error) in
       // no error then success
})
```

Inside Firebase Console the phone number is linked with the user's email:

[image]

When I try to access the phone number using the below it's coming up as nil

```
guard let userPhoneNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.phoneNumber else { return }
```

I just updated my pods just now and this issue occurred, it didn't happen before that.

The current updated Podfile.lock:

```
  - Firebase/Auth (6.11.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (~> 6.3.1)
  - Firebase/Core (6.11.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.1.3)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.11.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.3.2)
  - Firebase/Database (6.11.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseDatabase (~> 6.1.1)
    - FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (~> 1.3)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.2)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (4.2.6):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.0)
  - FirebaseMessaging (4.1.7):
    - FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (~> 1.3)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.2)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 4.1)
    // ...
```

The old Podfile.lock

```
  - Firebase/Auth (6.8.1):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (~> 6.2.3)
  - Firebase/Core (6.8.1):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.1.1)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.8.1):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.2.3)
  - Firebase/Database (6.8.1):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseDatabase (~> 6.1.0)
  - Firebase/DynamicLinks (6.8.1):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseDynamicLinks (~> 4.0.5)
  - Firebase/Messaging (6.8.1):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseMessaging (~> 4.1.4)
  - Firebase/Storage (6.8.1):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseStorage (~> 3.4.1)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (6.1.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.2)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 4.2)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.1.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (1.4.0)
  - FirebaseAuth (6.2.3):
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.2)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
  - FirebaseCore (6.2.3):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.2)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.0.1):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.2)
    - FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (~> 1.3)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.2)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 4.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (~> 6.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 6.2)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - FirebaseStorage (3.4.1):
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
```

Comment: Did you check to see if `Auth.auth().currentUser` is nil, which means it was called before the user actually signed in?

Comment: I thought the same thing but I’m already logged into the app as that user. The code from my answer is inside a vc that’s only accessible after the user is logged in. I’ll double check though

Comment: @DougStevenson I just doubled checked and Auth.auth.currnetUser isn’t nil but the phone number is nil. The crazy thing is the other version before I downloaded the new pods works fine. I just checked that too.

Comment: If it seems like a regression in the behavior, please [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). Hmm... or maybe that should be on [Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what happened but I logged out, closed Xcode, deleted the simulator, deleted derived data, rebooted my cpu, started everything over and logged back in. It's working now.

There must've been some sort of corruption some way some how on the simulator. If anyone has this odd problem follow the steps above.